# Relations between NIM-addition and addition

Tags: group-theory, binary

I will note $\oplus$ the NIM-addition. This is a commutative group law.
To obtain $a \oplus b$, you decompose a and b in binary, and you sum like this : 
0+0=0 ; 1+0=1 ; 1+1 =0 (it's the xor operation).

For example, $3 \oplus 5 =6$, because 3 is 11 and 5 is 101 so their NIM sum is 110.

We rapidly see that $x \oplus 0=x$, $x \oplus x=0$ and  $2p \oplus (2p+1)=1$.

I'm looking for a way to easily obtain $(a+1) \oplus b$ or $(a-1) \oplus b$ or $(a\oplus b-1) $ (an explicite formula).

Thanks!

Comment: Let us consider 
$$(a+1) \oplus b.$$

I am not sure what you mean by an *explicit formula*, but I suppose you want a formula which expresses it in terms of $a \oplus b$.

If this is the intended meaning, this looks hard to get to me. Consider two extreme cases, the first one being
$$
a = 1110, b = 1001.
$$
Here you simply get
$$
(a + 1)\oplus b = a \oplus b \oplus 1.
$$
Now the second case is
$$
a = 1011, b = 101.
$$
Here 
$$
a + 1 = 1100, a \oplus b = 1110, (a + 1) \oplus b = 1001,
$$ 
and it's not obvious (at least to me) to find a pattern.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the difficulty... I tried to use a binary de composition $a= \sum a_i 2^i$ but it doesn't give anything. And there's no document speaking about it.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the operation of incrementing a non-negative integer by 1 is equivalent to changing the last block of "1"s in the binary representation to "0"s and then changing the digit just before that to a "1". If that block had length $k$, then the last $k+1$ digits of $(a+1)⊕b$ is exactly the bitwise negation of the last $k+1$ digits of $a⊕b$, and the other digits are exactly the same. For example:

$101100011111⊕111110001101 = 010010010010$

$101100100000⊕111110001101 = 010010101101$

There is really nothing much more we can say about their relationship without having to use some complicated formula.

Comment: What kind of complicated formula are you thinking of?

Comment: A formula complicated enough to obtain the length of the block as well as express if-statements, of course, since we ultimately need to distinguish between being before or after the block, and I'm certain there is no practical use for such formulae.

Comment: That's sad these additions do not act well together... Thanks anyway.